# requiredContentSizeIdentifiers is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

my code is

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier =ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    adView.delegate=self;
    self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

//when banner is loaded successfully
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

//when any problems occured
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

The code

```
currentContentSizeIdentifier

requiredContentSizeIdentifiers

ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait
```

is deprecated, so what do I replace it with, so it will still work?

I need to do this before I submit it, because if I don't, the app will get rejected.

Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You said this is a duplicate question, but my question doesn't get answered

Answer (score 12):

If you remove the offending lines of code and implement the one below, it will achieve the same result but it is not deprecated.

Remove:

```
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier =ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
```

Add:

```
[adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the issue. If you removed those lines of code and added NOTHING your code will still work just as well. This is NOT an actual replacement for `requiredContentSizeIdentifiers`, if you had them set to landscape, not portrait, and tried replacing the code with the above code you would see that your app starts breaking.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 comes with many new updates. There are so many autoresize controls are deprecated. `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` is also deprecated.

Here is link which will help you to solve this issue.

[autolayout example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2/)